# Render Text from HTML5 Canvas

Tags: selenium-webdriver, html5-canvas

My website has canvas which is drawing the org hierarchy.

That contain `the name, email, department` etc with image of the person. I'm running automation test using selenium and want to see if i can get the textual data from the canvas.

Is there any way in which i can get that data on the canvas as text.?

If i slice that portion as image, is there any `JS library` available which can give me text  from that image.

Can anyone help me on this issue?
Your help is much appreciated.
Best Regards.

Answer (score 2):

What happens on canvas, stays on canvas. Canvas is a bitmap so any text drawn to it is rasterized and then forgotten. The only way to extract text after this point is using OCR (and trust me, you will spend more time writing correction algorithms than actual code). But a couple of options exist if you feel masochistic: [Ocrad](http://antimatter15.com/ocrad.js/demo.html), [Tesseract](http://tesseract.projectnaptha.com/).

However, my recommendation is: Always go to the source! If you can access the original text source (used to draw to the canvas in the first place), use that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Once elements on the canvas are rendered, they are a vectorial image. There is no object recognition in the elements you've used to create your image, and thus, there isn't anything that stores the text you've used into the image.

However, in the same way you can link image positions and characteristics to programming objects, you could store your text information in a data structure which is updated at the same time it's being populated into the canvas image.

I mean... if you use some retrieval of database info to populate your canvas with name, email and department data, you can store that information in a data structure in addition to draw them into the canvas image.

Then, just retrieving the values stored on that object will do the trick.